# RTC Jazz user authentication logs

Tags: websphere, rtc, jazz

How can I know how many users have logged in the IBM Rational Team Concert(RTC) in the last 3 months and RTC is hosted on IBM websphere?
Our RTC is integrated with the Active directory for user authentication.

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/168074/detailed-user-logs), RTC itself does not have log audit.
Its webapp server might.

For example, see "[WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment 8.0.0 > Auditing the security infrastructure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_sa_secauditing.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0%2F1-11-9&lang=en)".